# Why is my output always the same when I input 3 same digits?

Tags: java

I've just started learning programming a few weeks back and today I stumbled across this question which I am stuck. The output from my code is always the same when I input 3 of the same digit number. For example, 111, 222 or 333. This is the question and the following is my code.

(Game: lottery) Revise Listing 3.8, Lottery.java, to generate a lottery of a three-digit
number. The program prompts the user to enter a three-digit number and determines
whether the user wins according to the following rules:

```
class Question15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        System.out.println("This lottery program generates a random three digit number. Please make a guess of the three digit number and the program will determines the result. ");
        System.out.println("Awards for the lottery program:");
        System.out.println("1. If the user input matches the lottery number in the exact order, the award is $12000");
        System.out.println("2. If all digits in the user input match all digits in the lottery number, the award is $5000");
        System.out.println("3. If one digit in the user input matches a digit in the lottery number, the award is $2000");
        System.out.print("Please enter your three digit number: ");
        System.out.println();


        int number = input.nextInt();
        int number_lastDigit = number % 10;
        int number_secondDigit = (number % 100) / 10;
        int number_firstDigit = number / 100;

        int randomNumber_firstDigit = randomNumber / 100;
        int randomNumber_lastDigit = randomNumber % 10;
        int randomNumber_secondDigit = (randomNumber % 100) / 10;
        System.out.println("The generated random number is: " + randomNumber);

        if (number >= 100 && number < 1000) {
            if (randomNumber == number) // FIRST PRIZE
            {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! Your winning award is $12000!");
            } else if (number_lastDigit == randomNumber_firstDigit && number_lastDigit == randomNumber_secondDigit && number_secondDigit == randomNumber_firstDigit && number_secondDigit == randomNumber_lastDigit && number_firstDigit == randomNumber_secondDigit && number_firstDigit == randomNumber_lastDigit) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! Your winning award is $5000!"); // SECOND PRIZE
            } else if (number_lastDigit == randomNumber_firstDigit || number_lastDigit == randomNumber_secondDigit || number_secondDigit == randomNumber_firstDigit || number_secondDigit == randomNumber_lastDigit || number_firstDigit == randomNumber_secondDigit || number_firstDigit == randomNumber_lastDigit || randomNumber_firstDigit == number_firstDigit || randomNumber_secondDigit == number_secondDigit || randomNumber_lastDigit == number_lastDigit) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! Your winning award is $2000!"); // THIRD PRIZE
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please try again.");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.print("Please enter a 3 digit number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your current output and What kind of output did you expect?

Comment: This lottery program generates a random three digit number. Please make a guess of the three digit number and the program will determines the result. 
Awards for the lottery program:
1. If the user input matches the lottery number in the exact order, the award is $12000
2. If all digits in the user input match all digits in the lottery number, the award is $5000
3. If one digit in the user input matches a digit in the lottery number, the award is $2000
Please enter your three digit number: 
111
The generated random number is: 147
Congratulations! Your winning award is $5000!

Comment: I am expecting the output to be $2000 for this scenario.

Comment: `randomNumber_firstDigit = number / 100;` should probably be `randomNumber_firstDigit = randomNumber / 100;`. Same with the lines below.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber_firstDigit = randomNumber / 100;
int randomNumber_lastDigit = randomNumber % 10;
int randomNumber_secondDigit = (randomNumber  % 100) / 10;
```

Comment: I think you have a misstake that make randomNumber_*Digit.

Comment: And also 
          "  } else if (number_lastDigit == randomNumber_firstDigit && number_lastDigit == randomNumber_secondDigit && number_secondDigit == randomNumber_firstDigit && number_secondDigit == randomNumber_lastDigit && number_firstDigit == randomNumber_secondDigit && number_firstDigit == randomNumber_lastDigit) {"
is not right.

Answer (score 0):

probably the radom numer's digits should be calcluated from randomNumber that you are genrating not from the input you are taking from user.

```
int randomNumber_firstDigit = number / 100;
        int randomNumber_lastDigit = number % 10;
        int randomNumber_secondDigit = (number % 100) / 10;
```

this should be

```
int randomNumber_firstDigit = randomNumber / 100;
        int randomNumber_lastDigit = randomNumber % 10;
        int randomNumber_secondDigit = (randomNumber % 100) / 10;
```

hope this resolves :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a mistake in the your code.

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
```

The *randomNumber* will locate between 0 to 1000(except 1000). So *randomNumber* can also be 0~99, which can make the player will never win the award with the restriction below.

```
if (number >= 100 && number < 1000)
```

You need to revise to below.

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 900) + 100;
```

*randomNumber* will locate between 100~1000(except 1000).